# GWT :FlexTable widget counts in a row

Tags: gwt, gwt2

Can anyone guide me to calculate counts of **widget** in a [FlexTable](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlexTable.html)'s specific row ? I can get row counts by `table.getRowCount();` but I have no idea for counts of element or widgets in a specific row.
For example.....

> row 1 >>>> 5 widgets
>   row 2 >>>> 3 widgets

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am fine with this..

> table.getRowFormatter().getElement(row).getChildCount();